# Getting the co-ordinates of an element

Tags: javascript, html

How to get the co-ordinates of an element after onclick event ? I need to place an overlay just below an icon that was clicked.

Is there any such built in function provided by Javascript rather than manually writing a function for that ?

Comment: It's an area that can be more complex than it seems. I'd recommend the use of a good library to save you time and trouble, whether it's [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). They'll also do a lot of *other* things to smooth over browser differences, provide utility functionality, and let you concentrate on what you're actually trying to build.

Comment: To answer the direct question: no, there's no such built in function. You have to use the `event` object at some event handler to extract the position of the element.

Comment: @T.J. As per the question history, OP is using PrimeFaces, which ships with jQuery and YUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In YUI, I use the getXY() function that returns the absolute page position of any object in the DOM.  The source for that function in YUI2 is here: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/Dom.js.html.

In jQuery, it looks like you would use the .offset() method of a jQuery object: http://api.jquery.com/offset/.

You can either use one of those or look at their implementation and see how they work to code your own.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
function getGlobalPos(el) {
  var p = {x:0,y:0};
  while (el) {
    p.x += el.offsetLeft;
    p.y += el.offsetTop;
    el = el.offsetParent;
  }
  return p;
}
```